# Use async pipe with "||" operator doesnt work correctly

Tags: angular, async-pipe

I would like to use async pipe with "||" operator but I dont know how. For example:

```
<div class="col-md-12" *ngIf="(someSubscription$ | async) as users || someCondition">
```

Comment: Wrap the first part in parenthesis, `((user$ | async) as users)`.

Comment: Thanks for answer but it didn't work...

Comment: *ngIf="(user$ | async)? || isUpdate"

Comment: I  need "as users" :)

Comment: sorry but something incoherent in your request, if `user === null` and `isUpdate = true`, you won't be able to use `user`. So why do you need both? You should separate it in 2 distinct cases.

Comment: Its just an example, not a real use. I'm fixing the question

Answer (score 3):

You can use parentheses to combine the output of the async pipe and the condition.

```html
*ngIf="(someSubscription$ | async) || someCondition as output"
```

Assuming that `someSubscription$` isn't an `Observable<boolean>`, you can then perform a strict test to differentiate `output`.

```html
<div *ngIf="(someSubscription$ | async) || someCondition as output">
  <div *ngIf="output === true else other">
    output from someSubscription$ must be falsy
  </div>
  <ng-template #other>
    {{output.name}}
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zxzg9v